# 'Binary number number to base-10' program

Tags: javascript

In my es6 compiler, I was working on a function that converts any binary number into a base-10 number. basically, the 1s and 0s are all defaulting to 1.

This project is just 4 a 12-yr-old's pleasure (me) so, no rush if there's someone else with something for their job. anyway, I found the problem was in the fact that when you entered the binary number, the numbers stored in `convertedNumQuery` somehow defaulted to 1, even if the number was 0. I've tried debugging everywhere, but maybe it's just cause i'm a newb >.<

```
var numQuery = prompt("Enter a binary number to convert to base-10! Don't leave the \"0b\" in there.").split("");
var binaryChart = [1];
var convertedNumQuery = numQuery.map(Number);
var base10 = 0;
console.log(convertedNumQuery+ "\n");
for (var i = 0; i < (numQuery.length - 1); i++) {
    binaryChart.unshift(binaryChart[0]*2);
    console.log(binaryChart);
}
console.log(convertedNumQuery);
console.log("\n convertedNumQuery is array: " + Array.isArray(convertedNumQuery));
for (var i = 0; i < convertedNumQuery.length; i++ ) {
    if (convertedNumQuery[i] = 1) {
        base10 += binaryChart[i];
        console.log(convertedNumQuery[i]);
    }
}
console.log(base10);
```

say the binary number I wanted to convert is 101010, or 42. the expected result, 42, is supposed to be stored in `base10`, but what ends up happening is every number in `binaryChart` is added to get 63. and even stranger, when I looked at `convertedNumQuery` in line 15 `console.log(convertedNumQuery[i]);`, the array was logged in the console as all 1s.

Comment: `convertedNumQuery[i] = 1` needs to be `convertedNumQuery[i] == 1`.

Comment: thxxxxx so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why don't just use [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/parseInt) to convert:

```
params : (number,base)
```

```js
console.log(parseInt(110101, 2))
```